# get a faulty design after the rotation

Tags: css, html

I added css to a div

```
.rotate { 

height: 50px;
width: 50px;
padding: 1px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;
    margin-top:45px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* safari/chrome */ 
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* firefox 3.5+ */ 
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3); /* ie5.5+ */ 
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)"; /* IE8 */
  display:block; 
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow:hidden;
```

}

the displayed div presents ... in each vertical line !

[image]

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: you need to manage the height n width after rotation??????

Comment: I wanna display only ... at the end, not in each vertical line, 
and the design here is faulty !

Comment: So you want to imitate the "Some text blabla..." effect (for the whole text), but with CSS?

Comment: I wanna use ellipsis with a rotated text!

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is specifying to put `...` after a line of text that doesn't fit inside the element:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Make sure the text fits by changing the width and height.

---

### EDIT

Do you want to put `...` after all the vertical text? I think what you mean is this:

```
t t t
x x x
e e e
t t t
     
t t t
r r r
e e e
v v v ...
```

instead of:

```
. . .
. . .
. . .
t t t
     
t t t
r r r
e e e
v v v
```

but I don't think that is possible with CSS. Your text you put in the element should be something like this then:

```
vert text
vert text
vert text
.
. 
.
```

Then when you rotate it, you get this:

```
t t t
x x x
e e e
t t t
     
t t t
r r r
e e e
v v v . . .
```

There is no other way I can think of.

Comment: yes I wanna show the "..." but just at the end not in each vertical line

Comment: when I have a text which doesn t suit the div, I will show just the minimum and add ... after, with ellipsis I can do that
But when I add the rotation, that doesn t work as you can see the image, the ... are added in 2 lines here, the 4th line is faulty!

Comment: The fourth line is cut off, it's just the top end of the word. CSS `text-overflow: ellipsis;` only works on LINES of text, not text in the entire element.